# password strength meter component for delphi

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, password-checker

Does anyone know of password strength meter component for delphi Win32?

**Important :**
must be for a Win32 Form, not for Web.

something like that (but for Win32)

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something to *measure* the strength of a password, or something to *display* that measurement? There're really two independent things. The latter can be done with a simple label or progress bar.

Comment: @Rob, I'm looking for two features in a component : measure  the strength and display the measure   .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple to build your own...and you don't have to use much more than a TPanel, TEdit two TLabels and a TShape.

A Tshape component aligned left inside a panel and colored works great as the simple progress bar, just change the width % of the TShape to match the % strength.  Adjust color and such to match.  A good resource then for the % strength is to use one of the many [examples](http://www.codeandcoffee.com/2007/07/how-to-make-a-password-strength-meter-like-google-v20/) found on the web.  As an addition to this table, if you have a spell check component available, try to spellcheck the result...if it passes then it should get a much lower score (in my opinion -50 from the result).

In the onChange for the edit, recompute the password strength and adjust the other controls appropriately.

Comment: @ skamradt, I know it's not hard to create a component like this, but this time i prefer to use an existing

Comment: because I could not find a component, I wrote one myself. thanks